# Netbeans Git Push fails

Tags: git, netbeans, push

Following the [this video](https://137.254.56.27/media/github_nb.mp4) I've created a Git Local Repository for a small Netbeans Java project but the Remote->Push fails to connect. There's lots of reports of this going back several years, but no solutions that work for me.

What might I be missing?

What I did:

From NB:
Create a NB project Anagram4
Team-> Git -> Initialize Repository (the Local)
Team -> Commit (.git folder created)

Sign in to GitHub:
Click New Repository jagman653/anagram-4. Select HTTPS, and copy the generated URL to clipboard (https://github.com/jagman653/anagram-4.git)

Go back to NB and do Team->Remote->Push. 
Paste the URL ane fill in the form.
After clicking Finish I get this:
[image]

Comment: Could you describe here a bit more the matter of the problem? (settings, error message, etc.) The video is a plus, but it shouldn't replace the substance of your question I guess...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem was not related to Git Push. All my Internet interactions had been slow for some time, and finally stopped altogether. Rebooting the router solved the problem, apparently because that causes the ISP to assign a new IP address.

Upshot is if you get a 'failed to connect" on a Push or other Internet-related Git request, reboot your router.